# Code 107 invalid JSON when using parse REST API with AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, parse-platform

I am trying to use the Parse REST API to send push notifications but whenever I try and make an AJAX call, I get back an invalid JSON error in the response and a `400` status code. Here is my request

```js
$.ajax({
  url: 'https://api.parse.com/1/push',
  headers: {
    "X-Parse-Application-Id": "apID",
    "X-Parse-REST-API-Key": "restKey",
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  },
  data: {
    "where": {
      "appName": "CampMo"
    },
    "data": {
      "alert": "Test notification"
    }
  },
  error: function(e) {
    console.log(e);
  },
  success: function(data) {
    alert("success!");
  },
  type: 'POST'
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

The request works fine when I do it with a client like Postman but not when I am trying to do it through my web app. Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass your data as JSON stringified data

```js
$.ajax({
  url: 'https://api.parse.com/1/push',
  headers: {
    "X-Parse-Application-Id": "apID",
    "X-Parse-REST-API-Key": "restKey",
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  },
  data: '{"where": {"appName": "CampMo"},"data":{"alert":"Test notification" }}',
  error: function(e) {
    console.log(e);
  },
  success: function(data) {
    alert("success!");
  },
  type: 'POST'
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Wow that worked! Why did the way you formatted the JSON like that make a difference?

Comment: you are defined header `"Content-Type": "application/json"`